# what is the difference between "#msg" and "#msg div" in style tag?

Tags: html, css

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <style>
        #msg {
            visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            text-align:center;
        }

        #msg div {
            width:33.3%;
            margin: 100px auto;
            background-color:#0CF;
            border:#000;
            padding:thick;
            text-align:center;
            width:15%;
            size:50;
        }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="msg"><div>hello</div><a href="#" onClick="display()">Close</a></div>
    <a href="#" onclick="display()">click me</a>
 </body>
    <script>
        function display(){
            temp=document.getElementById("msg");
            temp.style.visibility=(temp.style.visibility=="visible")?"hidden":"visible";
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

this is the code which i found in internet. I made some changes. can anyone explain me why we using two div tag ?(one inside another)  and what is the difference between "#msg" and "#msg div"?

Comment: R u aware of div usage??

Comment: did u try in ur html code...varying the attributes and what effect it has on final output ?

Comment: `#msg` is an Id selector, so it will be applied to any element with the id *msg*. `#msg div` will only be applied to div-elements within an element with the id *msg*.

Comment: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/

Comment: yeah!! i understood now! thanks for responding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#msg` is for the div which has the id name `msg`

`#msg div` is for the divs which are present inside the `#msg` div.

Answer (score 2):

`#msg` will apply styles directly to the element with the ID `msg`, and `#msg div` will apply those styles to `div` elements inside that `#msg` element.

As or why to use two divs, one inside the other... you'd have to ask the original author of the code. There's no specific reason to do that.

Comment: and why that "close" option appears that far? how can i bring it near that pop-up?

Answer (score 1):

- `#msg` will apply to any element (should be one) with the `id="msg"`.
- `#msg div` will apply the styles to any `div` inside the element with `id="msg"`.

Answer (score 0):

`#msg` applies to the div tag with the id msg and `#msg div` to a div tag in a div tag with the id msg.

So the `#msg` in your case would aplly to this html:

```
<div id="msg"><div>hello</div><a href="#" onClick="display()">Close</a></div>
```

and the `#msg div` only to:

```
<div>hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**#msg** means it will access the element with the help of id.
hence style added to #msg will be applied to

```
<div id="msg>
```

And **#msg div** will access a Div tag which is inside the above Div

Answer (score 0):

`#msg` is the selector for an Item with the id msg. i.E `<div id="msg">...</div>` in your code.

`#msg div` references to a `div` element within an elment with the id msg. This matches `<div>hello</div>` in your code.

You might want to look at a [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors) (google it) for CSS Selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
#msg { ... }
```

This is an ID selector, denoted by the `#` and the ID text. It will target an individual element that matches the ID for example `<div id="msg">`

```
#msg div { ... }
```

This is a descendant selector. It will target all divs that are a descendant of `#msg`. A descendant can be at any level below the parent, unlike the child selector (`>`) which will only target direct children.

From [W3C docs](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/descendant):

> **Descendant combinator A B**
>   A selector of the form "A B" represents an element "B" that is an arbitrary descendant of some ancestor element "A".

```
can anyone explain me why we using two div tag ?
```

Nested divs are acceptable and common practice, however in your code sample the text would be more appropriately wrapped in `<p></p>` tags instead of having raw content inside a div.

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand with an example.

This is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gGKSf/1/)

HTML code:

```
<div id="msg">
  <div>
    stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#msg {
  width: 100px
  height: 50px
  background: red;
}

#msg div {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The first style "#msg" will be applied to the div containing the id as "msg" and the second style "#msg div" will get applied to the div which is inside the div containing the id as "msg" i.e it will be applied to the div containing the text "hello".

Comment: I didn't downvoted you, but maybe the problem is that you are linking w3schools, which is not a good source, see [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com)

Comment: Also, you say that *will get applied to the div **which is inside the div** containing the id as "msg"*, but the parent not necessary has to be a `div`, eg. you can have a `<ul id="msg">` with a `div` inside

Comment: I answered with relation to his question. I know it can be any